# problem in writing a function in jquery

Tags: jquery

this is my raw javascript code :

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" > 
  function S2T(e) {
  document.comments.comment.value = document.comments.comment.value + e;
  } 
</SCRIPT>
```

and i want to convert it to jquery function

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" > 
$(document).ready(function() {
  function S2T(e) {
  $("textarea#comment").val($('#comment').val()+e); 
 });
</SCRIPT>
```

html part

```
<a href='javascript:S2T('please')' >
```

i cant convert it , i just want to write function when i click on a icon , it adds to textarea

Comment: You're nearly there. Just take it out of the ready() in this case, and fix the quoting problem in your HTML part by using double quotes inside

Comment: uh thanks i thought that it must be correct . nice lesson :D

Answer (score 1):

Writing function definition in to $(document).ready() binds it to the [ready event](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) of the document. This means the code will execute once the page has finished loading. This isn't what you wanted.

Since you have jQuery loaded, you can simply use it within your already existing function, such as:

```
<script  language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function S2T(e) {
  $("textarea#comment").val($('#comment').val()+e);
}
</script>
```

And use it with your existing html:

```
<a href='javascript:S2T("please")' >
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define functions just as you used to, no need to put it in the ready() call:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" > 
  function S2T(e) {
     $("textarea#comment").val($('#comment').val()+e); 
  }
</script>
```

then make sure you don't use single-quoted javascript strings inside single-quoted HTML attributes:

```
<a href='javascript:S2T("please")' >
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" > 
  function S2T(e) {
    $("textarea#comment").val($('#comment').val()+e); 
  }
</script>
```

The document ready function is not necessary here. Also, you had a quote missing in the code.